# Best way to trace possible root cause of card fraud?

Tags: fraud

I recently had a fraudulent transaction on my debit card (in the UK, where I am based).  Having blocked the card, my main concern is to determine how much information has been stolen and how?

As this was an online transaction, the fraudster may have needed only superficial information regarding my card to complete the transaction e.g., expiry date, long card number and security code. These details could, theoretically, have been stolen while I used my card in person (at an ATM or while paying for goods) or they could have been stolen via hacking or phishing of myself or someone who has my details, which I would view as a lot more nefarious.

When I reported the transaction to my bank, I didn’t ask whether other auxiliary details were used in the transaction e.g.  my DoB, telephone number, security questions which may have been indicative of a wider problem.

I have no reason to believe that I am personally the victim of a hack or phishing. I use anti-virus and am careful with online transactions.

My questions are:

(1) Is it normal for banks to be able to give more information about a specific fraudulent transaction to their customers to help them understand how much information has been compromised?

(2) What is the best way to approach finding how much information may have been stolen and how?

Comment: If it was a magstripe transaction, anything that is on magstripe was stolen and attacker knew your PIN. It's not possible to make fraudulent EMV transaction on your account. What was the transaction mode?

Comment: @defalt. It was an online transaction. The attacker didn't need to use the pin to make the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your personal data is probably safe. Card theft happens all the time, and usually the thieves are after your card and nothing else. They usually sell cards wholesale (something called *dumps*) and don't care about monetizing your email, your passwords or anything unrelated to the card. That means your name, phone, and address could have been leaked, and little else.

1. No.

Banks usually don't give any information to you because doing so would disclose their investigation methods.

2. You cannot be sure.

Usually data is stolen when someone have your card in their hands, or copied when entered online. And you don't have any way to know how long it was between the time of the leak and time of usage.